# ways to choose 4 people including two or more male from N people with 1/3 male 2/3 female

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A sample of four people is randomly drawn from a population of N > 4 people.Assume that 1/3 of the total population is male, and 2/3 is female. (To simplify things, let’s assume that N is always divisible by 3). Assuming that all samples of 4 people are equally likely, what is the probability that two or more males are in the sample?

What I did: 
probability that two or more males are in the sample=

1-p(one male in the 4 people sample)-p(no male in the 4 people sample)=
$$1-{(2n/3\;choose3)*(n/3\;choose1)\over (n\;choose4)}*{}-({2\over 3}*{{2n\over 3}-1\over n}*{{2n\over 3}-2\over n}*{{2n\over 3}-3\over n})$$

Does it look right? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be $1-\frac{\binom{2N/3}{3}\binom{N/3}{1}}{\binom{N}{4}}-
\frac{\binom{2N/3}{4}\binom{N/3}{0}}{\binom{N}{4}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:
$${\rm P}(\text{no male in the 4 people sample})={2\over 3}.{{2n\over 3}-1\over n}.{{2n\over 3}-2\over n}.{{2n\over 3}-3\over n}$$
But it should be:
$${\rm P}(\text{no male in the 4 people sample})={2\over 3}.{{2n\over 3}-1\over n-1}.{{2n\over 3}-2\over n-2}.{{2n\over 3}-3\over n-3}$$Because after choosing a person, the total choices also decreases by one so it goes like $n,n-1,n-2,...$

---

$${\rm P}(\text{no males})=\frac{\binom{2N/3}4}{\binom{N}4}$$

$${\rm P}(\text{one male})=\frac{\binom{2N/3}3\binom{N/3}1}{\binom{N}4}$$

So:
$${\rm P}(\text{atleast two males})=1-{\rm P}(\text{no males})-{\rm P}(\text{one male})\\=1-\frac{\binom{2N/3}4}{\binom{N}4}-\frac{\binom{2N/3}3\binom{N/3}1}{\binom{N}4}$$

Comment: You have an error in your final line (you have subtracted "no males" twice)